# MSI - Conditionally register DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, atl

I'm working on a .NET profiler (my project output is a DLL). I have built 2 DLLs (written in c++) : one will be loaded by x86 .NET processes and the other by x64 ones. I want to generate a single MSI (targetting x86 patforms) that checks whether the OS is 64bits or 32bits. and then registers the correct DLL i.e :

```
 - Project output : - the_x64.DLL
                    - the_x86.DLL
 - A single MSI that targets x86 machines : contains the 2 DLLs
                    - if the OS is 64 bits then both of the DLLs are registered
                    - if the OS is 32 bits then only the x86 dll is registered
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSI platform does not support mixed 32/64 bit installers.  There are hacks to create 'hybrid' MSI's but it's not officially supported.   The approach recommended by Microsoft is to create 2 or more MSI's  ( common, 32bit provider, 64bit provider ) and then use a bootstrapper such as WiX Burn or InstallShield Suite Installers to provide a single install experience to the end user.